# Read xml from batch file and compare this value

Tags: batch-file, xml-parsing

I have an XML file. All I want is to read a particular tag value from this XML file using batch file and compare this value with other value.

My XML file is:

```
<cruisecontrol project="AAA">
<sourcemonitor_metrics>
  <project version="3.3">

    <metric_names name_count="15">
      <metric_name id="M0" type="number">Lines</metric_name>
      <metric_name id="M1" type="number">Statements</metric_name>
      .
      .
      . 

      <metric_name id="M13" type="average" values="block_depths">Average Block Depth</metric_name>
      <metric_name id="M14" type="average">Average Complexity</metric_name>
    </metric_names>
    <checkpoints checkpoint_count="1">
      <checkpoint checkpoint_name="NewcheckPoint" ignore_blank_lines="false">
        <metrics metric_count="15">
          <metric id="M0">34126</metric>
          <metric id="M1">15278</metric>
          .
          .
          .
          <metric id="M13">2.48</metric>
          <metric id="M14">3.34</metric>   <!-- Want to read this value in batch -->
        </metrics>
```

**## Please ignore the closing tags.**

I want to read  `<metric id="M14">` value.
I am very new to batch scripting.
Please suggest me how can I do this?

Comment: are you able to use powershell ?

Answer (score 1):

first, read `HELP FINDSTR` and try this simple command

```
 findstr /r /c:"\<metric id=\"M14\"\>[0-9,.]*</metric\>" my.xml
```

it finds the regular expression `"\<metric id=\"M14\"\>[0-9,.]*</metric\>"` inside the xml file and returns the matching line(s).

then read `HELP FOR` and try this command

```
 for /f "delims=^<^> tokens=3" %a in ('findstr /r /c:"\<metric id=\"M14\"\>[0-9,.]*</metric\>" my.xml') do @echo %a
```

it parses the returned line from the previous command using `<` and `>` as delimiters and returns the third parameter, that is the value required.